# Get cursor to end indefinite loop and display temp table data sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, temp-tables

I have this sql query with a cursor and temp table.

```
DECLARE @PartNo Char(22)
DECLARE @PartIssue AS CHAR(4)
DECLARE @Level AS INT
DECLARE @PartType AS CHAR(12)
DECLARE @TempLeadTime AS FLOAT
DECLARE @CumLeadTime AS FLOAT 
DECLARE @bomlforcursor  AS FLOAT
DECLARE @ldtimeforcursor AS FLOAT
DECLARE @temp_level as float
DECLARE @BomParent as NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ldt as NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ldt_cum as int
DECLARE @TestCursor as CURSOR
DECLARE @Blevel as INT
DECLARE @Bchild as NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Ptype as NVARCHAR(50) 
DECLARE @Bparent as NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Bqty as NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Ldtim as INT
DECLARE @Cissue as INT
DECLARE @Bmethod as INT
DECLARE @Rmethod as INT
DECLARE @Rqty as INT
DECLARE @Ldtime as INT
DECLARE @LdtimeforRQ as INT
DECLARE @cmldt as INT


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#CumLeadTimRep') IS NOT NULL 
begin
DROP TABLE #CumLeadTimRep
end

--CREATE TABLE #CumLeadTimRep (BOMLevel INT, bmchild NVARCHAR(50), parttype NVARCHAR(50), bomparent NVARCHAR(50), bmqty INT, leadtime INT, childissue NVARCHAR(50), bmethod INT, method INT, requiredqty INT, ldtime INT, ldtimeforRQ INT)
SELECT @PartIssue = drawissno, @PartNo = partnum, @Level=1, @PartType = sm FROM partmaster  where partnum = 'AE40-0287810'
WITH Hierarchyct(BOMLevel,bmchild, parttype, bomparent, bmqty, leadtime, childissue,bmethod,rmethod, requiredqty) AS
      (SELECT     @Level AS BOMLevel,
                        @PartNo AS bomchild, 
                        @PartType as parttype,
                        cast('' AS CHAR(22)) AS bomparent,  
                        cast(1.0 AS FLOAT) AS bomqty, 
                        (SELECT stleadtim FROM stock WHERE stocknum = @PartNo) AS ldtime,
                        @PartIssue as childissue, 
                        eccbom AS bmethod, 
                        eccroute as rmethod,
                        cast(1.0 AS FLOAT) AS requiredqty
                        --@CumLeadTime AS cumleadtime
      FROM eccissue 
      WHERE eccpart = @PartNo AND eccissueno = @PartIssue 

      UNION ALL
      SELECT            (hierarchyct.BOMLevel + 1) AS BOMLevel,
                        bom.bomchild, 
                        (SELECT sm from partmaster where partnum = bom.bomchild) as parttype,
                        bom.bomparent, 
                        bom.bomqty, 
                        (SELECT stleadtim FROM stock WHERE stocknum = bom.bomchild) as ldtime,
                        --(CASE WHEN (stock.stleadtim = 0 AND parttype = 'MANUFACTURED') THEN (bom.bomqty*routing.runtim) ELSE (SELECT stleadtim FROM stock WHERE stocknum = bom.bomchild) END) AS ldtime,
                        (CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(bom.bomissue)) = 'CURR' THEN (SELECT drawissno FROM PartMaster WHERE PartNum = bom.bomchild) ELSE bom.bomissue END) AS childissue,
                        bom.baltmethod AS bmethod,    
                        (SELECT eccroute FROM eccissue WHERE eccissue.eccissueno = (CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(bom.bomissue)) = 'CURR' THEN (SELECT drawissno FROM PartMaster WHERE PartNum = bom.bomchild) ELSE bom.bomissue END) AND eccissue.eccpart = bom.bomchild ) as rmethod,
                        (bom.bomqty * hierarchyct.requiredqty) AS requiredqty
                       -- @CumLeadTime + leadtime as cumleadtime
      FROM bom  INNER JOIN hierarchyct ON bom.bomparent = hierarchyct.bmchild 


      WHERE bom.baltmethod =(SELECT eccbom FROM eccissue WHERE eccissue.eccpart = hierarchyct.bmchild AND eccissue.eccissueno = hierarchyct.childissue )
      )

SELECT * INTO #CumLeadTimRep
FROM
(     
SELECT      hierarchyct.*,
CASE WHEN (stleadtim = 0 AND partmaster.sm = 'MANUFACTURED') THEN (Hierarchyct.bmqty*sum(routing.runtim)) ELSE stleadtim  END AS ldtime, --, SUM(1) as cumldtime
CASE WHEN (stleadtim = 0 AND partmaster.sm = 'MANUFACTURED') THEN (Hierarchyct.requiredqty*sum(routing.runtim)) ELSE stleadtim  END AS ldtimeforRQ,
@cmldt as cumldtr
--, SUM(1) as cumldtime
FROM  hierarchyct left outer join routing on part = bmchild and raltmethod = rmethod left outer join stock on stocknum = bmchild  left outer join partmaster on partnum = Hierarchyct.bmchild 
GROUP BY BOMLevel,bmchild, parttype, bomparent, bmqty, leadtime, childissue,bmethod,rmethod, requiredqty, stleadtim, sm, part
--Where leadtime =0Mr1990
) as temp
--SELECT * FROM #CumLeadTimRep

--PRINT 'BomParent' + '                ' + 'BomQty' + '              ' + 'FSunit';
SET @TestCursor = CURSOR FOR
SELECT * FROM #CumLeadTimRep

OPEN @TestCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM @TestCursor INTO @Blevel, @Bchild, @Ptype, @Bparent, @Bqty, @Ldtim, @Cissue, @Bmethod, @Rmethod, @Rqty, @Ldtime, @LdtimeforRQ, @cmldt ;
SET @ldt_cum = 0
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET  @ldt_cum = @ldt_cum + @Ldtime;
 INSERT INTO #CumLeadTimRep (cumldtr) VALUES (@ldt_cum);
FETCH NEXT FROM @TestCursor INTO @Blevel, @Bchild, @Ptype, @Bparent, @Bqty, @Ldtim, @Cissue, @Bmethod, @Rmethod, @Rqty, @Ldtime, @LdtimeforRQ, @cmldt;
END
CLOSE @TestCursor;
DEALLOCATE @TestCursor;
```

Instead of stopping at the end of the temp table, it goes in an infinite loop. How can i stop this? Also , it says "xx rows affected" rather than display the changed temp table. How can I get to display the change temp table?

Comment: And the CURSOR definition is? Let me guess you read from #CumLeadTimRep and insert to it?

Comment: Show us whole code. I guarantee this can and should be done without cursors.

Comment: @lad2025, updated the question with the whole code..

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas updaed the question, AFAIK since I use a CTE, need a cursor for this.

Comment: @NisalUpendra So I was right you loop through the same table you insert to it. Can't you just use 2 tables `#CumLeadTimRep_Input` and `#CumLeadTimRep_result` with the same structure???

Comment: To actually answer your question you *could* declare your cursor in the manner in which it is intended to be used - `LOCAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY`. Making it static means it will use a snapshot of your data captured when the cursor is opened, so when you make changes to the table the cursor does not reflect this change. Marking it forward only and read only (which it is) simply tells SQL server how it will be used, and it can allocate memory better. As a general rule avoid cursors, but if you have to use them then make them as simple as possible by declaring them properly.

Comment: **HOWEVER** his seems very much like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/179361), my guess is that you are trying to do some kind of cumulative sum, but since your cursor has no order, and you are only inserting the sum, so you have no reference as to which record which cumulative sum refers to.... It might be helpful to take a step back, and try and solve the problem you were having, rather than trying to fix your cursor.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, will study these and get back to the question.